# Creating a clean isolated compile environment for Linux C++ builds

Tags: c++, linux, build

Trying to bring some more quality into our build system and porting software recently to Android made me think that i do want a clean build environment where i don't accidently use dependencies to libraries and include files i do not want.

Is there something like Androids "make_standalone_toolchain.py" script which just creates a clean directory structure and provides the linux system headers and base libraries (like defined in Linux Standard Base LSB) and C and C++ runtimes?

Comment: Might be overkill but have you considered either a VM or standalone dedicated build machine?

Comment: I did and we have this as part of the CI process but i really want this on the local developer machine to enforce discipline before a faulty checkin and spending time debugging.

Comment: And i simply don't get how anyone think the 1970s unix way of pushing everything inside a /usr/include and /usr/local/include is still considered professional - but this is left for another unix rant at another time.

Comment: Maybe a container using lxc.

Comment: To clarify: No a container is not a solution. It must live on the development system with full access to IDE, debugger and whatever tool i have out of the box, i just want some clean header and library trees without compiler/linker falling back to the main system (like pkg-config is doing without a way to stop it).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider using a Docker container for it. I believe it will fully give you what you want since you'll have a clean Linux image.